# Double password during register

Tags: php, database, authentication, passwords, registration

I am working on a register and login page for a quiz game that i am making in PHP. I currently have the basics covered, but i im looking to make the registration with like a password check (double password) and also when the user enters the password i would like it to be covered and at the moment the password shows what the user is entering, can someone help me out with this, below is code i am working with:

Login

```
<?PHP

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $file = file_get_contents("data.txt");
  if(!strstr($file, "$username||$password"))
  {
    print '<script> alert ("Sorry! You have entered a Invalid Username or Password.");   window.location="index.php"; </script>';
  }
  if(empty($username))
  {
    print '<script> alert ("Sorry! You have entered a Invalid Username or Password."); window.location="index.php"; </script>';
  }
  else
  {
    header("Location: /home.php");
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:500px; border: 2px solid black;  margin:auto">

  <?php include "header.php"; ?>

  <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; width:500px; height:400px; float: left">
    <br>
    <form  align="center" method="post" action="index.php" >
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      Password:
      <input type="text" name="password" />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
      <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="document.location='registration.php'" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <?php include "footer.php"; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Register

```
<div align="center">
  <?PHP

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $file = file_get_contents("data.txt");
    $string = "$username||$password";
    if(!strstr($file, "$string"))
    {
      $myFile = "data.txt";
      $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
      $stringData = "$username||$password\n";
      fwrite($fh, $stringData);
      print '<script> alert ("Registration Complete"); window.location="index.php"; </script>';
      fclose($fh);
    }
    else
    {

      echo "Sorry the username: <b>$username</b> is already registered. Please use diferent  username.";

    }
  }

  ?>
</div>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:500px; border: 2px solid black; margin:auto">

  <?php include "header.php"; ?>

  <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; width:500px; height:400px; float: left">
    <br>
    <form align="center" method="post" action="registration.php" >
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      Password:
      <input type="text" name="password" />
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <?php include "footer.php"; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using flat file database to store the information.

Comment: input type='password' will hide the characters. As far as the checking a confirmed password, just put in a second field and name it something different. Then, check those vars for being set, then for being blank, then for matching.

Comment: oh rather simple, don't know why i didn't realize this, but thanks

Comment: @Omax Why don't you use jQuery for verification purposes?

Comment: Storing information as such in a plain text file, is not recommended. Use a DB instead, if at all possible. If this is not possible, then use `.htaccess` to deny access to the file, from the outside world.

Comment: i am learning how to use PHP and trying staying away from anything else as much as i can, i understand that some things could be done easier

Comment: I understand. However, do take into account that if someone "finds" your text file, will have access to your users' vital information. If a hacker "wants", a hacker "gets".

Comment: Sure i know what you mean, this is just for myself and it wont be published on the web. I of course would use better protection otherwise.

Comment: Plus you're not using any kind of encryption. Do look into what I've suggested. It's just a question of time, remember that.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Stay safe ;-) (an ounce of prevention, goes a long way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make your password field look like a password you need to change its type to password instead of text, so `type="text"` becomes `type="password"`, you also need to add another password field and change its name so you could confirm it.

Login

```
<form  align="center" method="post" action="index.php" >
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Password:
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Password (Confirmation):
  <input type="password" name="password2" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
  <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="document.location='registration.php'" />
</form>
```

Then at register, you need to grab the values sent in the request and compare them to each other(password and password2), if they're equal let the user continue, if they're not display an error message

```
<?PHP

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
  if($password != $password2) die('Passwords do not match');
  $file = file_get_contents("data.txt");
  $string = "$username||$password";
  if(!strstr($file, "$string"))
  {
    $myFile = "data.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "$username||$password\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    print '<script> alert ("Registration Complete"); window.location="index.php";    </script>';
    fclose($fh);
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Sorry the username: <b>$username</b> is already registered. Please use diferent  username.";

  }
}

?>
```

Comment: i was almost there, just few wrong lines, your answer helped, thanks